# Find regex pattern occurence as late as possible

Tags: regex, string, expression

I am trying to extract information from a string such as the following: `"Hello test 1 23 45 678 901 234 C test test2"`

I would like to extract `23 45 678 901 234 C`

The best regex I could come up with is `(\d\s?){13}C?` (C and the spaces are optional)

However, that regex extracts `1 23 45 678 901 23` instead of the pattern I want.
I know that regex scans the string from left to right, which explains this behavior... Is there any way to extract this information?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `(\d\s?){13,}C?`? Add a comma after `13` to match thirteen or more occurrences of a digit followed with an optional whitespace. Probably, `\d(?:\s?\d){13,}(?:\s?C)?` is better though. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/8dTw0g/1).

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks! I'll use your regex and keep only the last 14 characters for each match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest

```js
\d(?:\s?\d){13,}(?:\s?C)?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8dTw0g/1).

*Details*

- `\d` - a digit
- `(?:\s?\d){13,}` - thriteen or more occurrences of an optional whitespace and then a digit
- `(?:\s?C)?` - an optional occurrence of an optional whitespace and then a `C`.

You may choose the threshold you want, e.g. `{13,14}` or just `{14}`, and if `C` is obligatory, you need to remove the last `(?:` and `)?` and use `\d(?:\s?\d){13,}\s?C`.